# Excel VBA - Search a number in a column and copy adjacent cells in various textbox

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I was wondering if it´s posible the following in Excel VBA.

I have a form with a textbox and when I enter a certain number (unique number) into that textbox I want to search for that number in a especific sheet and column.

When that number is found for example en cell "A5", I want to copy cell "A6" to a text box in that form. And copy in "A7" in another textbox. And so on.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Yes this is possible.  Please show what you've tried so far.  If you need help getting started, have a look at the `Range.Find` method as well as the `Range.Offset` method.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate this, you should create:
a button (CommandButton1)
a text box (TextBox1) and
a label (Label1).

Column A will have the numbers,
Column B will have the whatever.

Now you click on button, corresponding on column B is shown. If no entry found, "No match found" is displayed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' decleration
    Dim row As Integer
        row = 1

    ' sheet name where data is
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select

    ' search column A for match
    Do While Range("A" & row).Value <> ""

        ' disply content if match found
        If Range("A" & row).Value = TextBox1.Text Then

            ' display
            Label1.Caption = Range("B" & row).Value

            ' exit loop because match is found
            Exit Do

        End If

        ' next entry
        row = row + 1

    Loop

    ' no entry found
    If Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
        Label1.Caption = "No match found"
    End If

End Sub
```

I hope this will help you accomplish what you need.

Edit: You can always change what to show, for example you decide to show column C or 1 row below the location where data is found, etc.